# Refering to 0° of longitude/latitude in a range

Tags: terminology

This is more of a question in diction...

In scientific writing, is there a preferable way to write a range, bounded by 0° longitude, in a way similar to "5° W to 10° E" if there is no cardinal direction for `0`.

The two ways that seem most reasonable to me are "0 to 5 degrees longitude" or "0° longitude to 10° E".

Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_meridian

Comment: @JanDvorak Thanks. I've updated my question title to be more specific. "Prime meridian" does not seem to read very well to me when describing a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"0 to 5 degrees longitude" sounds good. If you don't specify E/W, it is commonly assumed that you use signed coordinates.

Comment: Thanks! On that note, is it considered bad practice to use a combination of signed and un-signed and coordinates in one text?